# How to add IdeationBlog programatically to IBM Connections community

Tags: ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I am trying to add IdeationBlog to a community and then add Answer to the ideationblog created.

The API Documentation is vague enough to lose me. I am supposed to used the Blog API, but when I do that I am creating a blog entry.
I am posting tho this URL:
`/blogs/<Community UUID>/api/entries`
But when I dot that I am creating a blog.
I am posting the following document:
`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'>`
`<title type='text'>Test</title>`
`<content type='text'></content>`
`<category term="ideationblog" scheme="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/type"></category>`
`</entry>`

Do you know the URL I should send the document and do you know the document I should send.

Thanks.

Comment: found this post, will give it a try : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19640526/posting-blog-entries-to-a-community?rq=1

Comment: The solution from Suzanne (link in previous comment) works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the Ideation Blog application is required in a Community but is not there.

Applications are represented as Widgets in Communities: The links you can see lefthandside in the Community GUI are "Widgets" targeting to the corresponding "Application". Using the GUI you can add and remove Applications to Communities, and afterwards the added Applications will have an entry in the lefthandside Community menu (or not any more after removal).

Originally there was only REST support for this to execute programmatically. I have contributed basic functionality to add/enable Widgets to Communities to the Java SBT SDK. The code is available from SBT 1.1.3 upwards. The classes to look for are Widget, WidgetCommunity etc. Currently you can lookup and add Widgets in communities, but the code does not yet allow for removal of Widgets.